# Android sqlite helper error while getting data back

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hi all im using a sqlite helper class, but i have a little problem using a select statement.
I want to get the id of a datebase item by its name.

I use this select method:

```
public Cursor selectShift (String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, "name=" + name, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    db.close();
    return c;
}
```

And when i call this i use this:

```
if(handler.selectShift(name)!=null){
      Cursor c = handler.selectShift(name);
      id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
      c.close();      
  }
```

And then is get this error:

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested,
>   with a size of 0

As if its not exists, but i checked the name string is correct, and when i display the names in a listview i see that name, so it exists.

Can someone help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, i found the problem. It was in the cursor method, the solution is:

```
public Cursor selectShift (String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"_id"}, "name LIKE '"+name+"%'", null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    db.close();
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1 - there shoudld be check is there any data in cursor or not......c.getCount>0 or c.moveToFirst() or c.isAfterLast().......

```
if(handler.selectShift(name)!=null){
      Cursor c = handler.selectShift(name);

if (c.moveToFirst()){ //<--------------
   do{  //<---------if you not need the loop you can remove that
       id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
   }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}



  c.close();
```

}

2- not sure but looks in select query as '`<variable>`' are not there in where clause with variable

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + commentFieldName + " = '" + comment + "'";
```

or `better to use parametrized statement`

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName + " WHERE columnName = ?";
cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new Sring[] {comment});
```

Comment: hi, when i use the first i dont get any error, but the id=... never called, so i think the problem is somewhere in the selectShift(name) method, but i dont know why, i have another which is almost the same, selectShift(int id) and it works, i just changed the _id in the query to name

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be here

```
"name="  <-It should be "name = "+name
```

Following should work

```
Cursor cursor= db.query(TABLE_IMAGES,null, "name" +" = ?", new String[]{name},  null, null, null);
```

Comment: no, this is not the problem, the one is wrote is correct, i used that in another app without error

Answer (score 0):

Unless your name variable is already formatted (or not a TEXT) for sql I am guessing you need a little quotation.  Maybe something like this

```
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, "name= \'" + name + "\'", null, null, null, null);
```